# Problem faced when element add at last index position in Linked List

Tags: java, javac

// Here the class Linked List

```
public void add(int index, E element) throws Exception {
        
            Node<E> toAdd = new Node<>();
            toAdd.setData(element);

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
            }
         

       //enter code here
            temp.setNext(toAdd);
            temp = temp.getNext();
            temp.setNext(tmp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently, your question only consists of a title and code, with no description of the problem you're facing. That means we basically can't help you. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be give more information.

Comment: Please describe your problem … And you should provide the whole class, not only the `add()` method.